# Equivalent of selectNodes and selectSingleNode in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a old JS code, but i didn't find the equivalent of some JS old function.

- **selectNodes**
- **selectSingleNode**

***Here is the code*** :

```
function getFunctionProto( elem )
{
    var s = "";
    s += elem.getAttribute('name');
    s += "(";

    var oCat = elem.selectSingleNode( "ancestor(CATEGORY)" );
    var lParams = elem.selectNodes( "./PARAM" );
    if ( lParams != null )
    {
        for ( var i = 0 ;  i != lParams.length ; i++ )
        {
            if ( i != 0 ) s += ", ";
            s += lParams[i].getAttribute("name") + oCat;
        }
    }
    s += ")";
    return s;
}
```

***EDIT*** : 
I tried with a new function but it doesn't work as well, it tells me :

```
Error occurred while executing stylesheet 'f_api.xsl'.
Code: 0x80020009
Microsoft JScript runtime error
This object does not handle this property or method
line = 95, col = 3 (the line is broken from the beginning of the script block).
Error returned by the method or property call.
```

I tried with this code, who is recent on JS :

```
function getCategoryLabel( elem )
{
  var s = "";

  s += elem.getAttribute("name");
  var oAnc = elem;

  return s;
}
```

I called the function on the XSL code like this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:getCategoryLabel(.)"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both of these methods are for finding matches based on an XPath expression. They are still what you should be using if you want to find something with XPath.

Comment: I want to use these function in a XSL file with the ```msxsl:script``` in 1.0 version. Is it possible to do it ? Because when i try to compile the xsl i got an error message.. @ScottMarcus

Comment: Can you say exactly what error message you got, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` are functions exposed in the MSXML DOM API on nodes, since MSXML 3 usually to support XPath 1.0 based node selection. Your example `elem.selectSingleNode( "ancestor(CATEGORY)" );` however is not XPath 1.0 (that would say `ancestor::CATEGORY` I think), so it looks as if you have some very old code using the no longer documented predecessor of XPath 1.0 that pre MSXML 3 versions supported or some code not using the right XPath syntax.

The only way to use that stuff with Javascript within the browser would be by using `new ActiveXObject` where supported, for instance in Microsoft Internet Explorer. Or inside of MSXML executed XSLT and embedded J(ava)Script, as your earlier question seemed to indicate, but at least with XSLT 1.0 and current IE versions if you call a function directly from XSLT, even if you pass in a single node, on the script side you will receive an `IXMLDOMSelection` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757852(v=vs.85) so a function would rather use

```
function foo(domSelection) {
  for (var i = 0; i < domSelection.length; i++) {
    var node = domSelection[i];
    var node2 = node.selectSingleNode("ancestor::CATEGORY");
    ...
  }
}
```

and in XSLT you would use e.g. `pf:foo(.)` to pass a single node or e.g. `pf:foo(//bar)` to pass a node-set.

Comment: I edited my question, i tried with a new JS function where i only call an ```getAttribute```, but he doesn't seems to like it.. and i don't know why... :( @MartinHonnen

Comment: You have not supplied any context XML nor any XSLT context but as I have said twice, once in a comment and once above in the answer, even if you pass a single node from XSLT on the JScript side you receive an IXMLDOMSelection and of course that doesn't have any `getAttribute` method, rather you can use it the same I do in my example, i.e. access the argument by an index so if you don't change your parameter name then `elem[0].geAttribute("name")` should do. And as I have said too, it all depends on the XSLT processor, MSXML 3 and MSXML 6 have the API, XslCompiledTransform in .NET has another.

Comment: Thanks, the ```elem[0]``` helped me, but now i got this error : ```msxml4.dll
Unknown method.```. How can i resolve her, i need to include something special to accept the msxml4.dll on my xsl file ? @MartinHonnen